# Декомпилировать swf

Tags: декомпиляция, swf

Существуют ли программы для декомпиляции swf игр.
И есть ли методы защиты от декомпиляций

Answer (score 1):

Насчет игр не знаю, получится ли декомпилировать игру, но у меня получалось успешно декомпилировать баннер (владелец посеял исходники) с помощью Sothink SWF Decompiler 
и внести необходимые правки.

Comment: Я пытался этой же программой декомпилировать. Но при просмотре скриптов вылетает